# .htaccess URL rewrite directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

so I want to rewrite a URL. The default URL is http://example.com/m.php?i=random_string

Here's the rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^m/([^/]+)/?$ m?i=$1 [L]
```

However, when I access http://example.com/m/random_string, the page comes up but my external css and js files don't load. Why does this happen? I thought that the directory does not change from the original rewritten URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory indeed does not change, but browser doesn't know that - what it gets looks like a directory, such as `m/something`, so it tries to load the CSS file relative to this directory.

To fix that, use absolute paths to your CSS and JS in the page, ie.:

```
/css/style.css
```

(the initial forward slash makes it absolute)

---

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^m/([^/]+)/?$ m.php?i=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\?.*|)?$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do I have to create the "m" folder in my server?

Comment: No, if you use absolute paths, it will look at the root of your server - where the real css folder is, for example.

Comment: Ok, my code is written properly right? Because for some reason when I try to access the rewritten URL it redirects me to the original...

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it works perfectly, without any change.

Comment: @user3674778 Here, check it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64454818/TMP/www.zip

Comment: Do I need to make my PHP includes and requires absolute?

Comment: Nope, it works as usual. The rewrite is only a fancy way to show url to the browser.

Comment: I believe it's not working because I have a rewrite for PHP files. I just updated the question can you check it out?

Comment: Not really sure what you wanted but if I change the 3rd like to `RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`, it seems to work.

Comment: For some reason it's not working for me... without the 2nd and 3rd line it works fine, but with them it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't really work, I tried it now. What's teh second and third line meant to do anyway? Are they needed?

Comment: They make it so that index.php becomes index. They remove the .php extension

Comment: Ok try the thing I made now.

Comment: Perfect. The absolute thing helped a lot as well. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Also you may want the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and !-f things suggested in the other answer, the make sure valid paths don't get consumed by your rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^m/([^/]+)/?$ m.php?i=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will prevent first rewrite rule to be applied for real files and directories.

Comment: Works, great but I would have to do "m.php?i=$1" because the extension hasn't been removed yet, correct?